# How to replace addRange() for multiple selection in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, selection, addrange

I need to copy multiple nodeElements. Selection.addRange(), could help me but, Google Chrome removed this feature.

I tried to add multiple ranges and do string concatenation but formatting removing by using it.

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(articleText);

var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);

var titleRange = document.createRange();
titleRange.selectNode(articleTitle);
sel.addRange(titleRange);
```

I expect method or some tricks that could help me to add many selections.